# My checkboxes are invisible when unchecked

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a checkbox that i gave a border, so i can see it in the un-checked state. On the emulator and in AS this border can be seen but on my phone the border is not there. When you press the "invisible" checkbox on my phone it gets filled normally with the checkmark and color, but when its unchecked it turns invisible. This is the XML for the checkboxes:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:id="@+id/unfollowlay"
        android:layout_above="@+id/hi"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:src="@drawable/minus1"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            />
        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
            android:buttonTint="@color/red"
            android:id="@+id/unfollow"
            android:onClick="onUnfollow"
            android:scaleX="1.4"
            android:scaleY="1.4"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**edit:**

The theme setting in my manifest is:

```
 android:theme="@style/AppTheme
```

and the theme settings from my styles.xml file are:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
```

I am running the app both in the emulator, where the checkboxes diplays nicely, and on my phone (Android kitkat 4.4.4) where they are invisible when they are not checked.

Comment: Which Android version does the phone have?

Comment: Edit your question; Post the application Theme, as well as any intermediare Theme you might have applied. Also post where you are running the application (Emulator, Phone, Tablet, whatever), the OS version (I am guessing Gingerbread), the device ID, and the Build number... ( I suggest also googling that device/build for know bugs/weird behaviors)

Comment: what happens in onUnfollow?

Comment: I'd try changing the background color, to see if for some reason the unchecked state is getting a border of @color/white .

Comment: This worked, on my phone the checkboxes now are seen and they have a white border, altough they should have a red color: `android:buttonTint="@color/red"`Which they have in the emulator. This was wierd.